# Visual Studio Compile a VB.net application to NATIVE Executable

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, native, .net-native

I was wondering if you could compile your VB.net application to Native directly using Visual Studio.
I have already checked the "Compile" Tab under the project application settings and can't find anything related to compiling type.

Comment: You can, it's called _.NET Native_. See the following documentation article: [Compiling Apps with .NET Native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/).

Comment: After doing some research I've learnt that .NET Native works only with UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps, and not WinForms, WPF, etc. So if you're not targeting UWP I think you're out of luck.